# Python pandas time delta to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have imported a dataframe from an Excel file. The file contains a table of speed and duration in minutes. My ultimate aim is to convert this to a dataframe with even time steps at 1 second intervals. The speed should be repeated for each timestep. This is for import into another tool.

I'm struggling to understand where to start here. The only method I can find that seems like it might work is iterating over each row to calculate the timestamp and appending to a new dataframe. This seems really inefficient.

Can someone give me a steer here?

Sample input is below.

|  | speed | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 0.75 |
| 1 | 6 | 3.12 |
| 2 | 14 | 5.10 |
| 3 | 38 | 19.11 |
| 4 | 7 | 4.32 |
| 5 | 5 | 1.50 |
| 6 | 3 | 11.10 |
| 7 | 3 | 1.50 |
| 8 | 9 | 3.60 |
| 9 | 3 | 19.11 |
| 10 | 38 | 5.10 |
| 11 | 5 | 3.12 |
| 12 | 4 | 0.75 |

Sample output

|  | timestamp | speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 1 | 00:00:01 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 45 | 00:00:45 | 6 |
| 46 | 00:00:46 | 6 |
| 47 | 00:00:47 | 6 |
| .. | .. | .. |

Comment: please paste the code to generate the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a datetime index from the accumulated sum of the duration column, then re-index to 1-second frequency. When reindexing, use `method="bfill"` to fill backwards the existing values. Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"speed": [5,6,14],
                   "time": [0.75,3.12,5.10]})

# arbitrary date as reference
refdate = pd.Timestamp("2022-01-01")
df.index = refdate + pd.to_timedelta(df["time"].cumsum(), unit="min").dt.floor("s")

df = df.reindex(
    pd.date_range(refdate, df.index.max(), freq='1s'),
    method="bfill"
    )
```

```
df[df.index > "2022-01-01 00:00:43"]
Out[62]: 
                     speed  time
2022-01-01 00:00:44      5  0.75
2022-01-01 00:00:45      5  0.75
2022-01-01 00:00:46      6  3.12
2022-01-01 00:00:47      6  3.12
2022-01-01 00:00:48      6  3.12
                   ...   ...
2022-01-01 00:08:54     14  5.10
2022-01-01 00:08:55     14  5.10
2022-01-01 00:08:56     14  5.10
2022-01-01 00:08:57     14  5.10
2022-01-01 00:08:58     14  5.10
```